# Laravel blade "request()->is()" syntax issue

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-blade

I am using the following piece of code to make a link appear active.

`<a href="/profile/{{ $user->id }}" class="{{ request()->is('/profile/'.$user->id) ? 'text-blue-500' : '' }}">View Profile</a>`

It was working previously for links which weren't dynamic. But now when I'm passing data in the url it has stopped working. I've tried dd-ing the request()->is() part and it returns false although the url and the pattern matches.

Comment: You can compare with the current route : `url()->current()`. or use `is()` with the route name without parameters.

Comment: Are you using named routes ??

Comment: I would also advise you to use the `route()` helper to echo the href instead of hardcoding it. that way, if you ever change the route to for example /user/profile, all the links change too.